# How can I find unused symbols using cscope?

Tags: vim, refactoring, cscope

I am doing a little code refactoring. Usually, after I rewrite/reimplement everything, I do a clean-up first. This means, I remove unused libraries, unused functions etc.

My question is: How can I find functions that are not used anywhere? by this I mean there is only a definition and declaration and nothing more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is possible, I don't think cscope is the best tool in your situation.

You'll probably have more success by using a [static code analyzer tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis), that will also find other problems like non initialized or unused variables, dead code, etc.

I don't know which language(s) you are working with, but generally there are multiple open source solutions available.